# Winter 19 - VF pages's not rendering correctly

Tags: visualforce, winter19

We have been getting ready to go from Dev to Production and suddenly our VF pages have started rendering in a very strange way  - any help?[image]

Comment: can you check in Browser Inspect if there are any CSS loading issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you inspect the page you will notice that in the console a 500 error is occurring relating to the CSS on page load, which means the servers aren't sending lightning stylesheet data.  This started for me yesterday and is currently only an issue in Winter 19.

[image]

Comment: This issue is now listed in known issues for winter'19, [Lightning style sheet for VF page not working as expected](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000031OPQAY)